# C++ Regarding assigning value to Vector<Point> myVariable

Tags: c++

C++ Regarding assigning value to Vector myVariable

Hi guys.

I have this struct

```
struct Point
{
int x,y;
}
```

and in my main.cpp i got something like this

```
int main()
{
vector<Point> myPoints;

myPoints[0].x = 1;
myPoints[0].y = 1;

myPoints[1].x = 2;
myPoints[1].x = 2;

return 0;
}
```

and i get segmentation core dump, what is wrong with setting value to the element of the vector.

**Thanks for guiding!**

Comment: Have you called `myPoints.resize()` before, or any other reason to believe that there is a 0th element in the vector?

Comment: it should be a new vector, i create it then assign value but end up with segmentation core dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize any objects. You need to make the objects and then put them into the vector, otherwise you are acting on something that does not exist, which is causing the segfault.

Example:

```
Point myPoint;
myPoints.push_back(myPoint);
myPoints[0].x = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<Point> myPoints;
```

creates an empty vector of `Point` objects. Since it's empty, you can't access `myPoint[0]`, `myPoint[1]` etc. Attempting to do this won't auto-create elements; instead, it will invoke undefined behaviour – quite typically a segmentation fault.

Use `push_back` to append elements to the vector:

```
myPoints.push_back(Point(1,1));
```

or, alternatively, resize the vector so it contains default-constructed elements:

```
myPoints.resize(2);
```

You can also use an argument to the constructor of `std::vector` to resize it right at initialization time:

```
vector<Point> myPoints(2);  // auto-resizes the vector to length 2
```

---

*Note about `push_back`.* In C++11, you may use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()` as well: `myPoints.emplace_back(1,1);` appends a new element to the vector by calling the `Point` constructor in-place, using `1,1` as the arguments to the constructor. This is the most efficient way of appending newly created elements to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access elements which have not been created yet.

After this line:
    vector myPoints;

you have a vector `myPoints` which has exactly `0` elements. Thus, `myPoints[0]` is meaningless.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Create a vector with a pre-determined size: `vector<Point> myPoints(2);` (note: you can expand or shrink it later), then execute `myPoints[0].x=1` etc.
2. Use the vector's `push_back` method to add new elements to the vector, i.e. `myPoints.push_back(Point(0, 0));`
3. After you declare the new vector object, use the `resize` method to allocate space for two new elements.