# manipulating items in a vector within a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I feel so lost trying to figure this out.  I have my own data structure that I am planning on using vectors to avoid having to keep track of free space and reorginization that I would need to do if I used a simple array.  I don't don't know if I'm just not initializing properly or what, but every assignment I do seems to just disappear into thin air.

Here is some simple code to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int test_int;
    bool test_bool;
};

struct file
{
    vector<node> test_file;
};

int main()
{
    file myfile;
    int myint;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> myint;

    myfile.test_file[0].test_int = myint;

    cout << "Number entered is: " << myfile.test_file[0].test_int << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So basically it is a vector inside a struct.  It seems that the normal ways to access a vector don't seem to work, as in I can't read or write anything to the vector however things like `myfile.test_file.size()` seem to work (as in they return a '0' from a freshly created struct).  Trying to access the index directly by `myfile.test_file[0].test_int` results in a runtime error of `vector subscript out of range` as if it isn't actually there.

Am I not initializing it properly? This seems kind of ridiculous to me and I can't understand why it wouldn't work that way.

Edit:
Edited code to more clearly show behavior I'm referring to.  This compiles but gives a runtime error `vector subscript out of range`

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: `try.cc:26:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<node>::push_back(int&)’`

Comment: I'm aware it doesn't compile.  Attempting to assign values to any of the variables within the `test_file` struct fail to work properly. If you comment out `myfile.test_file.push_back(myint);` it will compile, but then you aren't even trying to modify the struct.

Comment: `test_file` isn't a struct. It's a zero-length vector.

Comment: OK, you seem to be confused why it doesn't compile. It doesn't compile because you're trying to push an `int` into a vector of `struct node`s.

Comment: @JasonM.: Why don't you show us something that does compile but does't behave in the way you expect. That'll make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @NPE Edited to show what I'm talking about, this still doesn't work as it hits a run time error, but it compiles.  I'm unsure how to get a working version of this.

Comment: The new error is due to the fact that you access the zeroth element although no element has been pushed to the vector. The vector is empty. See this question for how to get elements in the vector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115869/c-regarding-assigning-value-to-vectorpoint-myvariable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edited version doesn't work because you're accessing an element past the end of the vector:

```
    myfile.test_file[0].test_int = myint;
```

Before you can do this, you need to either `resize()` the vector, or add an element using `push_back()`:

```
    myfile.test_file.push_back(node());
    myfile.test_file[0].test_int = myint;
```

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work, just not how to make it work. It is the extra layer of complexity that is confusing me, how do you initialize a struct containing a vector of structs?

Comment: @JasonM.: I've added a suggestion to my answer.